# How do I declare a base model class in Flask-SQLAlchemy?

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I would like to declare a base class that all other schema objects
can inherit from, for example:

```
class Base(db.Model):
    created_on = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=db.func.now())
    updated_on = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=db.func.now(), onupdate=db.func.now())
```

Then all other schema objects can inherit from it and not have to repeat
the declaration of the two columns.

How would I do this in Flask-SQLAlchemy?

```
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(255), unique = True)
```

Answer (score 82):

SQLAlchemy offers a [directive called `__abstract__`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/api.html#abstract). You can use it to tell SQLAlchemy not to create the table for a particular model. That model can be used as your base class.

```
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Base(db.Model):
    __abstract__ = True

    created_on = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=db.func.now())
    updated_on = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=db.func.now(), onupdate=db.func.now())


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(255), unique = True)
```

Comment: This does the trick. Also, to simplify things a bit, you can remove the `__tablename__` in the children and instead add to the parent:     @declared_attr
    def `__tablename__`(cls):
        return cls.`__name__`.lower()

Comment: @Heliodor That would just be the default behavior you'd get without the `__tablename__` at all. `__tablename__` was specified because the OP wanted it to be plural `users` rather than singular `user`.

Comment: New link to doc: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/api.html#abstract

Comment: Thanks @siulkilulki. Updated.

Comment: @Heliodor, I tried `@declared_attr 
    def __tablename__(cls): 
        return cls.__name__.lower() + 's'` in the base class to pluralize, but it didn't work.  Any tips?